# Animate an SVG line when another div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to achieve this:

Click a Div with an onclick function, and then apply a css animation to an svg line. So far, is not working:( here's my code:

for the Icon that generates the animation:

```
<div class="hexagon1" onclick="ani()">
    <img id="hexagon-icon1" src="images/hexagon-icon1.png"/>
</div>
```

for the line that I want to animate:

```
<div id="left-line-animated-container-left">
    <img id="animationline" src="images/line-animated.svg">
</div>
```

the CSS for the animation:

```
.line-animated {
  -webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation;
  stroke-dasharray: 800;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s ease ;
  -o-animation: dash 5s ease ;
  -moz-animation: dash 5s ease ;
  animation: dash 5s ease ;
  display: block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 800;
  } 
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

and my JAVASCRIPT:

```
function ani(){
   document.getElementById('animationline').className ='line-animated';
}
```

Any suggestion:)? thanks!

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

Comment: chrome pal :) @ArifBurhan

Comment: For an SVG element, className is not a string, but an instance of SVGAnimatedString.

Comment: In your html you don't have a class called "line-animated"

Comment: @ArifBurhan no that's the name of the class on the css section, the id name is 'animationline' . I'm trying to achive to this svg with that id to get the  class on the css called line-animated.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think I'm not following you:( I'm a bit messy here

Comment: your javascript is invalid and undoubtedly results in errors in the browsers error console. className is not a string type in SVG, you cannot assign a string to it.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've tried with this and no results:( 

`       $(".hexagon1").click(function() 
{
    $('.animationline').addClass(".line-animated");
});​`

Comment: Corrected, the animationline wasn't a class but a div. changed to #animationline but no results

Comment: SVG is not html. read up on what className is in SVG here https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGStylable